# Error 503 with httpd localhost server on Fedora 35

Tags: linux, apache, fedora, http-status-code-503

So I switched to Fedora and wanted to install LAMP on it. So I followed this article: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-lamp-stack-on-fedora/. Everything has been installed successfully. Afterward, I wanted to change the default root directory. In order to achieve it, I edited /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and have set:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/muq/Localhost"

User muq
Group muq

<Directory "/home/muq/Localhost">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And now I am getting the error: **503 Service Unavailable**.

If I change User and Group to default (apache) the error I get is: **403 Forbidden**.

Previously I was doing the same thing with Apache on PopOS and it was working fine.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: /var/log/httpd/error_log says:
`failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS`

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the step in the article which says to set SELinux to permissive? My guess is that you didn't, and that's what's happening: SELinux is preventing user home directory files from being served out by the web server.

You could just follow the advice in the article and just turn it off. But, I strongly recommend that you don't. The thing it's protecting you from here is a reasonable one — a misconfiguration could otherwise very easily expose personal user files to the internet. And here's the key thing: fixing this is really easy! At least as easy as the instructions for disabling SELinux in the article! You just need to do:

```
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/muq/Localhost
```

to label that directory as one from which you *want* to serve httpd content. And that should do it — and still give you all the *other* protection of SELinux.

(You could also consider a location like `/srv/www` or `/var/www/html` as your web root, keeping your home directory out of the whole thing. These are parts of the filesystem *designated for that*, and to me as a former sysadmin seems cleaner. But the choice is yours.)

Comment: Hey. Thank you for this reply. Unfortunately, this didn't work. I did follow the step about SELinux in the article, and also I did run your command, but this hasn't changed anything. Maybe there is something more to do about that. Anyway, I am now working well within /var/www/html folder. I had many problems with this folder permissions. Eventually, I have created a subfolder within, changed user/group to muq, I configured /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and also had changed user/group in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf.